# Spring Batch JdbcBatchItemWriter commit is recommiting the records

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I am having `skip-limit==commit-interval` and value is `100`. If 1 of the record is failed due to integrity i need to skip and others should not be affected and need to log that failure which i am able to do with `SkipListenerSupport` but the issue is my other records are having unique check constraints on columns so which are getting fired due to that 1 record failure as that records are getting committed again or what? The issue is not happening if i set commit-interval=1.

```
<skippable-exception-classes> 
    <include class="org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException"/>
</skippable-exception-classes>
```

Comment: If skiped exception is thrown in the writter the whole transaction is rolled back and then each item from the chunk is reprocessed and written one by one.

Comment: are you writing into a db? make sure that you your datasource configuration has "autocommit=false", otherwise it will indeed commit the entries which were processed before the failing entry twice.